# Как подставить текст заголовка в ссылку?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, текст заголовка в src ссылки и переходил по ней?

Пример ссылки:

```
https://yandex.ru/maps/35/krasnodar/search/(сюда подставить текст заголовка)
```

```html
<h1>Изумрудный город</h1>

<a href="">Кнопка</a>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1112126/308951 кто кого дублирует ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно почему сразу не подставить в ссылку, но если требуется делать именно js'ом, то например так.

```js
const anchorLinks = document.querySelector('[data-js=searchLink]');
const title = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;

anchorLinks.href = `https://yandex.ru/maps/35/krasnodar/search/${encodeURIComponent(title)}`;
```

```html
<h1>Изумрудный город</h1>

<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка</a>
```

Для нескольких ссылок:

```js
const anchorLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js=searchLink]');
const title = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;
const searchHref = `https://yandex.ru/maps/35/krasnodar/search/${encodeURIComponent(title)}`;

anchorLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.href = searchHref;
});
```

```html
<h1>Изумрудный город</h1>

<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка 1</a>
<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка 2</a>
<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка 3</a>
```

Comment: Все отлично работает, спасибо. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы применялось ко всем кнопкам, а не к первой по структуре?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

```js
const title = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;
const mapURL = `https://yandex.ru/maps/35/krasnodar/search/${encodeURIComponent(title)}`;
const anchorLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js=searchLink]');

anchorLinks.forEach(link => link.href = mapURL);
```

```html
<h1>Изумрудный город</h1>

<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка 1</a>
<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка 2</a>
<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка 3</a>
<a href="" target="_blank" data-js="searchLink">Кнопка 4</a>
```

Начальный код взял у @MedvedevDev, чтоб автору вопроса было проще разобратся)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть задачи, тогда так: добавляем к заголовку уникальный `id`, а на кнопку вешаем обработчик события `onclick`. Перед переходом по ссылке `href` сначала отрабатывает скрипт, который ее заполняет.

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Изумрудный город</h1>
  <a href="" target="_blank" onclick="buttonOnClick(this)">Кнопка</a>
  <script>
    function buttonOnClick(button) {
      let heading = document.getElementById("heading").innerText;
      let baseUri = "https://yandex.ru/maps/35/krasnodar/search/";
      button.setAttribute("href", baseUri + encodeURIComponent(heading));
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Только работать оно здесь не будет в связи с ограничительными политиками.

Answer (score 0):

Это немного не так работает, про якоря можно почитать [здеся](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/A), [тута](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya) и в гогле

Пример:

```html
<a type="button" href="#archor">move to</a>
<div style="padding-bottom:200%;"></div>
<p><a name="archor">Some title</a></p>
```

Comment: Про якоря я знаю, мне необходимо, чтобы с моего сайта переходил на яндекс.карты и искал заголовок

Comment: @QuickBrownFox https://learn.javascript.ru/popup-windows#dostup-k-popapu-iz-osnovnogo-okna

Answer (score 0):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('a');
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.location = `https://yandex.ru/maps/35/krasnodar/search/${h1.innerText}/`
});
```

```html
<h1>Изумрудный город</h1>

<a href="">Кнопка</a>
```