# Как подставить текст заголовка в ссылку через JS?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, заголовок с классом `.maintitle` подставлялся в конец пути этой ссылки и переходил на неё?

```html
<h1 class="maintitle">Музей Искусств</h1>
<a class="map-link" href="https://yandex.ru/maps/krasnodar/">Ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mapLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('map-link');

for(let i = 0; i < mapLinks.length; i++) {
  mapLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let headerText = mapLinks[i].closest(".wrapper").getElementsByClassName("maintitle")[0].textContent;
    location.href = mapLinks[i].getAttribute("href") + headerText;    
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="maintitle">Музей Искусств</h1>
  <a class="map-link" href="https://yandex.ru/maps/krasnodar/">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Возможно ещё понадобиться UrlEncode

Answer (score 0):

Про якоря можно почитать [здеся](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/A), [тута](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya) и в гогле

Например:

```html
<a type="button" href="#archor">move to</a>
<div style="padding-bottom:200%;"></div>
<p><a name="archor">Some title</a></p>
```